# Can't resolve binding in bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android

I am getting error constantly in binding.bottom_navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> { I am attachig the code below please have a look and give some solution to it.

```
       ActivityMainBinding binding;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());

        binding.bottom_navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.bnav_categories:
                        replaceFragment(new GalleryFragment());
                        break;
                    case R.id.bnav_latest:
//                    replaceFragment(new GalleryFragment());
                        break;
                    case R.id.bnav_home:
                        replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                        break;
                    case R.id.bnav_popular:
                        replaceFragment(new SlideshowFragment());
                        break;
                    case R.id.bnav_Random:
//                    replaceFragment(new GalleryFragment());
                        break;


                }

                return true;


        });

    }
```

The error I am getting is:-

```
MainActivity.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
        binding.bottom_navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
               ^
  symbol:   variable bottom_navigation
  location: variable binding of type ActivityMainBinding
```

The activity_main.xml file is:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 
 
 
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.949"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: Include error in your question, so one can know the actual issue.

Comment: @FrenyChristian I have attached the error I am getting. Please have a look

Comment: also include the layout file `activity_main.xml`

Comment: In the mainactivity.java file i am getting two errors
1- binding.bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
2- switch (item.getItemId()) {

Comment: The activity_main.xml file:-

Comment: @MDP i have attached the activitymain.xml file please have a look

Comment: If you are using Android Studio it gives you the name as `bottomNavigation` not with an underline. if it doesn't you should `clean` your project and `rebuild`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the name of the java file matches the name of ActivityMainBinding
like the photo

HomeActivity

[image: 1]

MainActivity

[image: 2]

Comment: Next time, please review before and after posting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set id in BottomNavigation in xml

```
android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
```

Try to use it as

```
binding.bottomNavigation..setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
      //add code
});
```

**With viewbinding views' ids are automatically converted to camelcase**